# How to pass info with NSURLConnection instance so I can get it from connectionDidFinishLoading

Tags: iphone, ios, nsurlconnection

I am using `NSURLConnection` to load data from a response. It works as it should, the delegate method connectionDidFinishLoading has the connection instance with the data I need. The problem is that I want to pass some information along with the request so that I can get it when the connection finishes loading:

1. User wants to share the content of a URL via (Facebook, Twitter,
   C, D).
2. `NSURLConnection` is used to get the content of the URL
3. Once I have the content, I use the SL framework
       S`LComposeViewController:composeViewControllerForServiceType` and need
       to give it the service type
4. At this point I don't know what service the user selected in step 1. I'd like to send that with the `NSURLConnection`.

Can I extend `NSURLConnection` with a property for this? That seems very heavy-handed. There must be a "right way" to do this.

Many Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming you don't need the delegate-based version of the `NSURLConnection` process for some other reason, this is a good use case for the block-based version:

```
- (void)shareContentAtURL:(NSURL *)shareURL viaService:(NSString *)service
{
    NSURLRequest *urlRequest = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:shareURL];
    NSOperationQueue *queue = [[NSOperationQueue alloc] init];

    [NSURLConnection sendAsynchronousRequest:urlRequest queue:queue completionHandler:^(NSURLResponse *response, NSData *data, NSError *error)
    {
        if ([data length] == 0 && error == nil) {
            // handle empty response
        } else if (error != nil) {
            // handle error
        } else {
            // back to the main thread for UI stuff
            [[NSOperationQueue mainQueue] addOperationWithBlock:^{
                // do whatever you do to get something you want to post from the url content
                NSString *postText = [self postTextFromData:data]; 

                // present the compose view
                SLComposeViewController *vc = [SLComposeViewController composeViewControllerForServiceType:service];
                [vc setInitialText:postText];
                [self presentViewController:vc animated:YES]; 
            }];
        }   
    }];

}
```

Since blocks can capture variables from their surrounding scope, you can just use whatever context you already had for the user's choice of service inside the `NSURLConnection`'s completion block.

If you're still wed to the delegate-based `NSURLConnection` API for whatever reason, you can always use an ivar or some other piece of state attached to whatever object is handling this process: set `self.serviceType` or some such when the user chooses a service, then refer back to it once you get your content from the `NSURLConnectionDelegate` methods and are ready to show a compose view.

Comment: Reason for staying with delegate based connection can be simple - block based version does not work under iOS4.3, it was introduced in iOS5.0.

Comment: Not a bad reason in general (at least if you're trying to support an already released app; iOS 4 is pretty old for new development). But `SLComposeViewController` isn't on iOS 4.x either, so presumably one needn't worry about that for this case.

Comment: Very elegant solution rickster, I never would have thought of this! Cleans up my code considerably. Unrelated (?) but interesting, for Twitter I'm getting a crash that it's trying to update the UI from not the main thread, but FaceBook works fine. Hmm.

Comment: The completion block on that `NSURLConnection` method isn't guaranteed to be run on the main thread, so anything inside it that touches the UI needs to be put on the main thread. There are at least a couple of nice block-based ways to do that -- I've edited my answer to show one of them.

Comment: What is the purpose of the queue? The documentation says "The operation queue to which the handler block is dispatched when the request completes or failed."  It seems like something internal

Comment: The `queue` parameter allows you to control when/where the completion handler block gets executed. If you want it to happen on the main thread, pass `[NSOperationQueue mainQueue]`; if you have other work that you're organizing on background queues, you can slot it in one of those; or if you just want it to run in the background, you can use a throwaway `NSOperationQueue` instance as in my example. (That last option is a good idea if you want to do some nontrivial processing on the fetched data before bouncing back to the main thread to update the UI.)

Answer (score 1):

You could check the `URL` property of an `NSURLConnection` instance and determine the service by parsing the `baseURL` or `absoluteString` property of the `URL` with something like `- (ServiceType)serviceTypeForURL:(NSURL *)theURL;`

All the `NSURLConnectionDelegate` methods pass the calling `NSURLConnection` object-so you could get it from

`- (void)connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *)connection`

or

`- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didFailWithError:(NSError *)error`